# Expected length of a path in a hyper graphs

Tags: probability, random-variables

Assume in a graph we represent each node by k bits. Rout is a path that connect a node with its destination and is unique. for example, from node 000 to node 111 we need a rout with length 3 and that rout contains vertices 100 and 110.

I was wondering what is the expected length of a rout in this graph? With complete explanation please.